How to save custom ivs stream video in s3 bucket
Im working in a project where after live streaming, aws automatically stores the recorded video in s3 bucket in following pattern
some-bucket-name/
ivs/
v1/
856720175319/
3ZJUthfjTh/
2024/
4/
6/
6/
1/
985Hytjs0kCB/
media/
hls/
1080p/
is there anyway to store the recorded sessions in a customized path ?
Im using Nodejs for this project
below are the tried code.
  const recordChannel = async (args) => {
      let name = args.name

      try {
          const input = { 
              name: name+"-record",
              thumbnailConfiguration: {
                  recordingMode: aws.RecordingMode.Interval,
                  targetIntervalSeconds: 60,
                },
                recordingReconnectWindowSeconds: 30,

              destinationConfiguration: {
                  s3: {
                  bucketName: 'some-bucket-name' //---- this is all  
                                                     // it has
                  }
              },
            };
          
          const createRecordingConfigRequest = new 
        aws.CreateRecordingConfigurationCommand(input)
          const recordResponse = await 
          client.send(createRecordingConfigRequest)
          console.log("=========== recordResponse",recordResponse)

          return recordResponse.recordingConfiguration.arn
        } catch (err) {
          console.error('Error creating channel:', err);
          throw err;
        }
  }

following are the reffered links but none of them seems to help.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/awse-using-amazon-ivs-and-mediaconvert-in-a-post-processing-workflow/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ivs/latest/LowLatencyUserGuide/create-channel-auto-r2s3.html
https://dev.to/aws/auto-recording-amazon-ivs-live-streams-to-s3-m64
